# Can I change the x-axis value in the Repast Simphony GUI Time Series chart?

Tags: repast-simphony

When creating a time series chart in Repast Simphony, the x-axis is automatically the Tick Count. **How can I make a custom Time Series chart with something else, like UTC time, on the x-axis?** I'm essentially using the tick count as epoch seconds from the start time of my simulation, but it would be much more useful to me to be able to see my sim time in UTC on the x-axis.

I've poked around a little bit in the source code, but it looks like the x-axis is pretty much set at tick count. I'm looking for what classes/interfaces to extend/implement to get the time series chart with an x-axis that I want.